# Eclipse - Omit extenisons

Tags: eclipse, preferences

I'd like to know how to omit the extensions of .java files from the name tabs in the UI.

if I have more than 5 java files open the rest get thrown into the continued list due to writing .java 5 times already. This is a minor inconvenience.

So how do I get the names tabs to hide extensions? (even if just .java files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to hide the extensions, you can only choose the editor tabs position (top,bottom). you find the available options in the menu

Windows -> Preferences - General - Appearance